# A setting type as object with predefined structure

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, package.json

Is there a way to enforce the structure of an object setting?

For example `package.json`:

```
{
  "contributes": {
    "configuration": {
      "properties": {
        "myextension.mysetting": {
          "type": "object",
          "default": {
            "anyKey": {
              "property1": "",
              "property2": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The setting `myextension.mysetting` is an object type, where key `anyKey` could be any string at user's choosing and `property1` and `property2` are the only acceptable properties in that object. If user attempt enter other property name (i.e. `property3`) it should show it as not an acceptable property.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the property

```
"additionalProperties": false
```

to the scheme where you define `property1`and `property2`

Answer (score 0):

With @rioV8 answer this is the solution I was looking for:

```
{
  "contributes": {
    "configuration": {
      "properties": {
        "myextension.mysetting": {
          "type": "object",
          "patternProperties":{
            "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": false,
              "properties": {
                "property1": {"type": "string"},
                "property2": {"type": "string"}
              }
            }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "default": {
            "anyKey": {
              "property1": "",
              "property2": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```